# User and Permission table distorted in Civi/WP

Tags: wordpress, permissions

I'm trying to configure Civi 4.63 on WP 4.2.2. and the rows for the users and specific permissions don't line up. I tried expanding the Permissions column to be a single line (like the User columns) with no luck. Here's what I get:

[image: Screenshot of Users and Permissions table]

I'm new at WP, but this was a whole lot easier in Drupal.
Any advice will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Slightly hacky way around it: zoom out. In Chrome that's CTRL and -.

Comment: That worked, but I'll need a magnifying glass to read the screen.